# Delphi Win32 Receiving a datatable from ASP.NET service

Tags: delphi, soap

I'm building a Delphi Win32 app that should consume a Soap Service, which turns out to be a .NET based app. One function returns a DataTable. Of course, Delphi Win32 (not Delphi .NET) has no way of understanding this natively.

Any way I can make it work? I'll be happy to parse the XML manually too, but I've no idea how to get hold of the raw XML response.

The WSDL: https://stratus.voxamvia.co.za/api.asmx?WSDL

The function: GetNotifications which returns GetNotificationsResult, which builds as:

```
  GetNotificationsResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fnamespace: WideString;
    Fnamespace_Specified: boolean;
    FtableTypeName: WideString;
    FtableTypeName_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setnamespace(Index: Integer; const AWideString: WideString);
    function  namespace_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SettableTypeName(Index: Integer; const AWideString: WideString);
    function  tableTypeName_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property namespace:     WideString  Index (IS_ATTR or IS_OPTN) read Fnamespace write Setnamespace stored namespace_Specified;
    property tableTypeName: WideString  Index (IS_ATTR or IS_OPTN) read FtableTypeName write SettableTypeName stored tableTypeName_Specified;
  end;
```

Any help appreciated!

Would it help if I implement RemObjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your dataset from xml. This should give you a starting point: http://www.gekko-software.nl/DotNet/Art07.htm and http://www.gekko-software.nl/DotNet/Art08.htm.

I haven't used DataAbstract from RemObjects, so I can not give an advice on it.

LE: you can access and consume a web service written in .net by following this simple article well written by drbob - [Consuming C# Web Services with Delphi 7 Professional](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin45.htm)

which contains also a small example on how to build dynamically and how to use the THttpRio (is the same as the Mikael Eriksson's answer)

Answer (score 1):

> Any way I can make it work? I'll be happy to parse the XML manually
>   too, but I've no idea how to get hold of the raw XML response.

You can get it in the [OnAfterExecuteEvent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Rio_TRIO_OnAfterExecute.html) on your [THTTPRIO](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SOAPHTTPClient_THTTPRIO.html) component. There you will have  `SOAPResponse: TStream` as a parameter.

**Update:**

To get the event to fire you add a THTTPRIO component, create the event handler and use the RIO component as the third parameter to `GetAPISoap`.

This worked for me. HTTPRIO1 is a component on the form.

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: APISoap;
begin
  A := GetAPISoap(False, '', HTTPRIO1);
  A.Validate_User('', '');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't figure out how to get my OnAfterExecuteEvent to trigger. It's simply dead while my I call the soap service.

Comment: @Hein - I've edited my answer to point you to a small example with THttpRIO